# No feedback after submitting closed question for review

Tags: discussion

My question was closed 4 days ago for being off-topic

[Programming Exercises UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/143838/programming-exercises-ux)

I made the necessary changes in order to comply with the guidelines, following the feedback I was given. I haven't heard anything from a moderator since I submitted the question for review. Are there any steps I can take in order to draw attention to my question so it can be considered for re-opening? This hadn't ever happened to me; usually, my question would be opened again in a few hours since my edit.

Comment: I don't see your question anymore. Perhaps submit again?

Comment: @Izquierdo, It was reopened on Jul 18, then deleted 6 days later by the post author.